# How is dynamic memory allocated in two dimensional array?

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, new-operator

Tried to understand the allocation memory in heap but confused
What is the difference them :

```
int** p=new int*[n];
```

**vs**

```
int*p=new int[n];
```

2)the first line of code int** p=new int*[n] this is confusing a lot what does int*[n] return and new int*[n] return.

Comment: do not spam tags. it has nothing in common with the `C` tag.

Comment: In general, `new T[N]` constructs an array of size N, where each element is of type T and returns the address of the array (of type T* which is equal to that of the first element). So the first gives you an array of pointers to int , the second gives you the an array of ints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Comment: @churill Sorry my unserstanding is incorrect. I thought that `n` is a variable. It might be just representing a fix number. The second one get the start address of the array of int, is `decay` not a proper word?

Comment: It is not two dimensional array only array of pointers.

Comment: @churill I got it, thank you. I'll remove my comment to prevent confusion. "Dynamic" allocation is not related to VLA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is exactly as the code shows

```
int* p = new int[n];
```

allocates `int`, but

```
int** p = new int*[n];
```

allocates `int*`.

You can allocate anything (more or less). If you allocate `T` then what you get back is a pointer to `T`, i.e. `T*`.

But there's nothing special about pointers, they can be allocated too. So if you allocate `T*` (a pointer to `T`) then what you get back is a pointer to a pointer to `T` (i.e. `T**`).

Allocating pointers is the first step to allocating a 2D array. A 2D array is just an array of 1D arrays. The pointers are the rows in the 2D array (if you like) but the columns still need to be allocated.

```
int** array2d = new int*[num_rows]; // allocate the rows
for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i)
     array2d[i] = new int[num_cols]; // allocate the columns for row i
```

After executing this code `array2d` is a dynamically allocated 2D array with `num_rows` rows and `num_cols` columns.

Comment: Then you should not use the term "2D array" in your answer as it wrong and misleading

Comment: @P__J__ Not now that you've pointed out the issue. Sometimes it's OK to use terms loosely.

Comment: No it is not. By language definition the array  is a continuous chunk of memory. I can `memset(array2d, 0, sizeof(array2D));` but I cant do it with array of pointers. It is not a 2D array and IT language is precise.

Comment: @P__J__ Well I disagree. Context is what matters. I'm answering the question in terms that I hope the OP will understand. Obviously in a different situation I might be more precise.

Answer (score 3):

The second line of code allocates an int array of size `n`, no problem with it.

The first line **does not allocate a 2D array**. It just allocates an array of pointers. If can be used to mimic a 2D array with an *array of pointers to arrays*:

```
int **p = new int*[n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    p[i] = new int[m];
}
```

It then looks like a 2D array of size n*m, in the sense that you can use `p[i][j]`, except that rows are not contiguous.

But remember: when coding in C++, always prefere standard containers to manual allocation.

Comment: It is not a 2D array!!. It is the **array of pointers** and it is something completely different.

Comment: @P__J__: Yes, and that's the reason why I used a bold font in my answer to state that is was not a 2D array.

Answer (score 2):

First of all - it is not two dimensional array. It is an array of pointers.

```
int** p=new int*[n];
```

then you need to allocate space for every row by iterating through this array.

To create **two dimensional** array you need to:

```
int (*x)[n] = new int[n][n];
```

Comment: The problem with the second approach is, that `n` needs to be a compile time constant in C++. C could do it with a runtime `n`, but not C++.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica C++ does not support VLAs so it has to be constant in both.

Comment: Nope. The outer dimension in a `new <type>[n]` statement may be dynamic, and should be in almost all cases. Otherwise `std::vector<>` would not be implementable. Only the `<type>` part must be known fully at compile time.

Comment: `new <type>[n]` is not considered a VLA because the result is a pointer to the first element with the type `<type>*` which does not contain a dynamic array size anymore. And because `new <type>[n]` with a dynamic `n` has been allowed since the conception of the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

A 2D array can be dynamically allocated in C using a single pointer. This means that a memory block of size row*column*dataTypeSize is allocated using malloc and pointer arithmetic can be used to access the matrix elements.